# Disable Apache on El Capitan 10.11.4

Tags: macos, apache

How do I disable Apache running because I can't get it down since I cannot run this `sudo apachectl stop`. It will give me this

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

but when I run this `httpd -v` then it will give me this

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
```

To my mind, if the server run, of course it will consume memory and space. Why is it running automatically?

Comment: In Terminal, what's the output of `ps auxw | grep [h]ttpd`?  If it's nothing then `httpd` isn't running.  The output of `httpd -v` is just doing as it's supposed to, report the version information and that does not mean the service is up and constantly running, only that `httpd` executed and terminated after reporting the version info.  Also, did you look in Activity Monitor to see if `httpd` is running?